# Mac Preview app: Background color in full screen mode

Tags: pdf, preview, fullscreen, color

The macOS Preview app has the option to change the background color (the one behind, say, a pdf file).

However, in fullscreen mode it seems that the background color remains unchanged.

Is this a bug? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I think the default grey colour in fullscreen mode is a system-wide UI setting. Not sure if there is a plist file somewhere that could be altered to view the background different. However, you may consider investigating other pdf viewers that offer such functionality in fullscreen mode

Comment: Thanks for welcoming! Is there maybe a way to find out which plist file to configure?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn’t know which plist. Also if you’re on Big Sur, it would be potentially more complicated if it’s a system plist, because of the new SSV volume structure. I think you’re better off using another PDF viewer that may have capabilities to change background colour in full screen mode.

Answer (score -1):

System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Display Contrast

This gives you a sliding bar from which to adjust the system display contrast to your liking (i.e. difference between lightest & darkest display colors).

In my case, I had the same question and after some digging was happy to find this, I set mine to ~1 step up from "normal". I'm running Big Sur (11.4) on Macbook Air.

Comment: This is not directly changing the background color, it is changing the Mac internal display color. Sharing the file with someone having set a different contrast will make the background not the same color.